# Need to read several .h5 files using loop with indices

Tags: r, hdf5, rhdf5

I have been given a crap ton of files I need to read over and graph. Some of the datasets have more files that other. So I need to write a loop that will do this. The code that I have written so far works but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to index the loop to call the files.  I have tried a simple

```
i <-0 
for (i in files){
i <- i + 1
file_[i] <-H5fopen(files[i])
 }
```

I have tried other versions but I have changed it so much I can't remember. But when I load the files individually at the bottom. They load So I know that everything before the area where the loop is needed works.

```````
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(Rtools)
library(tidyr)
library( dplyr)
library(scales)
library(readr)
library(tools)
library(plotly)
library(rootSolve)
library(stringr)
library(rhdf5)

library( ggplot2)
library(tokenizers)
library(readr)
library(tools)

library(stringr)
library(h5)
options(max.print=10000)
options(digits = 5, scipen = -2)



askUser_file_x <-0
while(askUser_file_x != "none"){

  askUser_file_x <- readline(prompt="Please, type on DS you wish to analyze, else type none (format DS##):   ")


  x <- str_extract(askUser_file_x, "(?<=DS)[0-9]+")
  x <-as.numeric(x) 
if (x==23){
  setwd("/H5files/08/14/")

  }else if  (x>=24 & x<=26){
    setwd("C:/H5files/08/15/")

  }else if  (x>=27 & x<=30){  
    setwd("C:s/H5files/08/21/")
  }else if  (x>=31 & x<=36){  
    setwd("C:/H5files/08/20/")

  }else if  (x>=01 & x<=06){
    setwd("C:/H5files/08/21/")
  }else if  (x>=37 & x<=44){
    setwd("C:/H5files/08/21/")
  }else if  (x>=07 & x<=18){
    setwd("C:/H5files/08/26/")
  }else if  (x>=19 & x<=22){
    setwd("C:/H5files/08/27/")
  }else if  (x>=45 & x<=46){
    setwd("C:/H5files/08/28/")
  }else if  (x>=47 & x<=50){
    setwd("C:/H5files/08/29/")

  }else
    print( "Data Set does not exist")



switch(askUser_file_x,
       DS01= (file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(282:286))),
       DS03= (file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(266:271))),
       DS04= (file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(272:276))),
       DS05= (file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(277:281))),
       DS06= (file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(290:294))),
       DS07= (file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(316:320))),
       DS08 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(321:325))),
       DS09 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(326:330))),
       DS10 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(331:335))),
       DS11 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(295:300))),
       DS12 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(301:305))),
       DS13 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(306:310))),
       DS14 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(311:315))),
       DS15 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(336:340))),
       DS16 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(341:345))),
       DS17 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(346:350))),
       DS18 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(351:355))),
       DS19 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(356:360))),
       DS20 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(361:365))),
       DS21 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(366:370))),
       DS22 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(371:375))),
       DS23 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(100:115))),
       DS24 =(file <-paste0("TIVA_000",c(116:121))),
       DS25a =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(121:125))),
       DS25b =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(126:130))),
       DS26 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(131:133))),
       DS27 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(161:163))),
       DS28a =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(146:150))),
       DS28b =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(156:160))),
       DS29 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(151:155))),
       DS30 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(156:160))),
       DS31 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(164:170))),
       DS32 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(171:175))),
       DS33 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(175:180))),
       DS34 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(181:188))),
       DS35 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(189:193))),
       DS36 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(194:198))),
       DS37 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(199:198))),
       DS38 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(211:220))),
       DS39a =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(221:230))),
       DS39b =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(231:240))),
       DS40 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(241:243))),
       DS41 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(244:245))),
       DS42a =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(246:249))),
       DS43a =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(250:252))),
       DS44 =(file<-paste0("TIVA_000",c(253:255)))

       )

    files <-paste0(file, ".h5")



 ## this is the part I need to loop some DS's have 3-5 files one has eleven

       file_1<- H5Fopen(files[1])  

       file_2<- H5Fopen(files[2])  

       file_3<- H5Fopen(files[3])

       file_4<- H5Fopen(files[4])

      file_5<- H5Fopen(files[5])

      h5ls(file_1)

``````
Edited for clarity

If I choose say DS23 then files becomes [1:6] TIVA_000116.h5 , TIVA_000117.h5, ... 
which is what I want, and if I run ``` file_1<- H5Fopen(files[1])``` it opens the files the way I expect it too. Is there a way  loop over files 
and create something like this 
````
file_1 <- H5Fopen(files[1])  # where file_1 take its name from  i = 1 and  
                             #H5Fopen(files[1]) is selected from the 1 element in the files vector
````
I want it to be able to select them because I have 45 Data sets of 5 files each that have to be created and converted. So I am trying to automate as much as possible. 
THanks in advance
```````

Comment: What is `files`? You seem to be using it as a numeric vector `(i + i)` and as a vector (perhaps of file names in `i in files`). But why are you incrementing the index of a for loop? The whole point is that the for loop does that automatically? You don't need a loop. If files is a list of file names, `file <- lapply(files, H5fopen)` will load them all and store them in a list.

Comment: Yes, lapply works to open each file individually. How would I be able to call each one individually if need be? Also some of the datasets have a different number of files that can be select some have 3, 4, 5 and 11. I need the code to be recognize that variation.

Comment: `file[[1]]` gets the first one, etc. I don't know the structure of `H5f` objects is but you would access the parts the using file[[1]] as the base name. If you want to name the parts something like `names(file) <- files` or perhaps `basename(files)` should do it. Most good tutorials on R basics discuss how to work with lists.

Comment: for(i in seq_along(files)) { 
        nam <- paste0("file_", i)
        assign(nam,files) 
      }  # this function assigns the variables like I want BUT the assign populates all the elements of files  in each variable. So now I need to be able to separate each element from files and reassign it to the corresponding file_#

Answer (score 0):

This was the specific code that answered my needs for something that would open all files from the switch case regardless of how many of them there were.

``````
data_subsets<- purrr::map2(H5_files, askUser_test_1,  h5read)
df <-purrr::map_dfc(data_subsets, "Data", H5Fopen)

`````
``````